# Sets and probability

Tags: probability, permutations

The number of total outcomes of an experiment are $25$. If $A$ and $B$ are two non-empty independent events of the experiment such that outcomes in favour of event $A$ are $15$, then the minimum number of outcomes in favour of event $B$ can be?

Comment: One? I mean, since $\;B\neq\emptyset\;$ .

Comment: @Joanpemo the answer I have is 5.

Comment: Then I think some information is missing from the question.

Comment: @Joanpemo Most probably not

Comment: I think it's not hard to come up with an experiment with 25 possible outcomes and two independent events of it, one with 15 favourable outcomes and the other one with any number between 1 and 10 favourable outcomes. For example, the experiment "choose a number between 1 and 25", and A=choose a number between 1 and 15, B=choose a number between 16 and 25.

Comment: @Joanpemo I think here A and B are not independent as if one happens the other cannot.

Comment: I really don't understand your comment. Why do you think that? Are you assuming, for some reason, that in this case both events happens at the same time or something like that?

Comment: @Joanpemo I'm saying that the question says that A and B are independent events. But in your comment A and B are not independent according to me as the event of occurrence of A negates the event of occurrence of B

Comment: Have the outcomes equal probability to occur?

Comment: For me independent events are those for which the fact that one occurs doesn't affect the probability of the other one occuring (this is not the formal definition but pretty close). I could be wrong but I think the events in my example  fulfill this condition.

Comment: If $B$ has size $k$ and $A\cap B$ has size $\ell$, one asks that $1\leqslant\ell\leqslant\min(15,k)$ and that $\frac{15}{25}\cdot\frac{k}{25}=\frac{\ell}{25}$, that is, $3k=5\ell$. Thus, $3k$ must be a nonzero multiple of $5$. The smallest $k$ such that this happens is $k=5$. Now, if $k=5$ and $\ell=3$, $A$ and $B$ are indeed independent hence the answer is $$\color{red}{\bf 5}.$$

Comment: @Joanpemo "the events in my example fulfill this condition" Actually they do not.

Comment: @Did put it as an answer. You are correct.

Comment: Thank you Did. Can you please explain or prove why not?

Comment: @Joanpemo Assuming that neither of P(A) nor P(B) is zero, then P(A⋂B)=0 but P(A)P(B)≠0, so they are not independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose that $B$ has $b \gt 0$ equally probable favourable outcomes, while $A$ has $15$.

Then $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B) = \frac{15}{25} \times  \frac{b}{25} = \frac{3b}{125}$ given $A$ and $B$ are independent.  But since there are only $25$ possibilities for $A \cap B$, $3b$ must be a multiple of $5$, so $B$ must have $5$, $10$, $15$, $20$ or $25$ favourable outcomes.

The smallest of these is $5$, as Did seems to have commented while I was typing.